# How to order by field called "count" in Prisma?

Tags: prisma

I'm having hard times to find out how to order by `count` field in Prisma.

The query looks like this:

```js
const where = // ...
const limit = // ...
const skip = // ...
const data = await this.prisma.translation.findMany({
      where,
      take: limit,
      skip: offset,
      orderBy: {
        count: 'asc'
        // ^ here is the issue, because count seems to be reserved for aggregations
      }
    });
```

Prisma model:

```
model Translation {
  id           String
  count        Int      @default(0)
}
```

I found the docs here https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#orderby but it does not say anything how to say to prisma that the count does not mean aggregation but a column name.

The error I'm getting:

```
Invalid `prisma.translation.findMany()` invocation:\n\n\n  Failed to validate the query: `Assertion error: Attempted conversion of non-map ParsedInputValue (Single(String(\"asc\"))) into map failed..` at ``
```

PS. I found this issue on GitHub that is still open https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7806, gonna ask also there for some workaround or something...

Thanks for any help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in [Prisma Version 3.0.1](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/releases/tag/3.0.1).

If you need to solve this in Prisma v2, you could change the field name in prisma and use the `@map` annotation to point to the `count` column in your database table.

Example Prisma schema

```
model Translation {
  id                      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  transactionCount        Int      @default(0)  @map(name: "count")
}
```

Inside your prisma code you would use `transactionCount` instead of `count`. But there won't be any change to the underlying database, which will still have the column named `count`.

For more info, take a look at the Prisma docs for [using custom field names](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/use-custom-model-and-field-names).